# Alphabetical view sorting in multilingual site not working for translated content

Tags: i18n-l10n, views

I have created a view that alphabetically lists all nodes of type "*glossary entry*". A glossary with many terms. Besides German I need the glossary in English, too. The translation has worked great using Entity Translation module. I only have the problem that the alphabetical order of the English version is not correct. The English glossary has the same sort order than the German (original) version:

> **German version:**
>
> 1. Adler (German word for eagle)
> 2. Hund (German word for dog)
> 3. Kuh (German word for cow)
>
> **English version:**
>
> 1. Eagle
> 2. Dog
> 3. Cow

I crawled many forums but couldn't find a solution for my problem. I already added the relationship *"Entity Translation"* in my view but the additional filter and sorts don't help me here.

What I need is a sort *"title (English Translation)"*. Does somebody has a clue how to get this work?!!

[Please find here the view's query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0HUL.png)

Comment: Did you install the title module?

Comment: Yes, I have installed that.

Comment: You have to make sure you don't add the field "Content: Title
The content title" in your view. This i the core drupal title. You have to add the title field title. Can you report back if this fixes your problem?

Comment: Thanks Robin, but I am aware of this. My content type contains the title of the Title Module and so does the sort criteria that I added in my views.

Comment: Yes the sort criteria, but is your field you are displaying also the correct title field?

Comment: Yes, definitively it is.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your query (that is executed by views)?

Comment: I posted the screenshot in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that by adding this field as a relationship to the view and so **`name:field`** became accessible as sort criteria, which I then chose instead of **`content:field`**.